# Dropbox iOS SDK (Obj-C) authorisation with dropbox app installed produces error (app needs to be updated)

Tags: authentication, authorization, dropbox-sdk

I'm using the Dropbox iOS SDK installed with cocoapods to authorise a user in order to upload files to DB.
This works, as long as the DB-App isn't installed on my device (the authorisation is then made via Safari).

As soon as I install the DB-App and try to allow my app to use DB (in the DB-App), I'm getting an error saying:
«myApp» needs to be updated. The developer needs to update this app so it works with this iOS-Version. (or something along these lines - had to translate the error from German).

I'm building the app with the latest XCode and SDKs, using a current signing-profile, etc.
The app works totally fine under the latest iOS version.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/iOS-SDK-Obj-C-authorisation-with-dropbox-app-installed-produces/td-p/704340 ]